# Screen Capture Complications with WPF window on top

Tags: wpf, screenshot

I need to capture the entire screen with a transparent WPF window as the topmost window.
I tried 2 approaches:

1. using System.Windows.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen
2. using WINAPI GetDesktopWindow

Both methods yield the same result. I get the entire screen EXCEPT my topmost transparent WPF window.
The WPF window w is created with:

```
w.AllowsTransparency = true;
w.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;
w.Background = new SolidColorBrush( Color.FromArgb( 1, 0, 0, 0 ) );
w.Topmost = true;
```

plus some content of course. The window covers the entire screen surface.

Apparently, the WPF window draws on a surface that is not included in GetDesktopWindow.

Can anybody pls shed some light on this and share some ideas how to truly get the entire screen surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution:

As far as I can tell there is no solution for the Graphics.CopyFromScreen approach because you'd need to OR CopyPixelOperation.CaptureBlt with CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy but you can't. The usual M$ inconsistency madness...

However, the WINAPI approach works since you can combine SRCCOPY and CAPTUREBLT when using BitBlt. Without CAPTUREBLT transparent and layered windows will not be included.